# Linux Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS boots up with an error

Tags: boot, dual-boot

First of all, I'm using a translator, so it might be a little awkward.

I was trying to dual-boot Windows 11 and Linux Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, and yesterday I installed Ubuntu on top of my laptop that already had Windows 11 installed. After installing Ubuntu, it worked fine until yesterday, but today when I tried to boot into Ubuntu again, I got an error like the one in the attached picture, and it wouldn't go past the Ubuntu loading screen. I googled and found that I just need to add something like 'ACPI=OFF' in GRUB and boot, and I tried it, but it only made a few of the error codes go away, but it didn't go to the same Ubuntu loading screen.

This is the error I get when Ubuntu boots.

[image: This is the error I get when Ubuntu boots.]

- my laptop is Lenovo Thinkbook 16p g3 arh
- CPU: Ryzen 6600H
- GPU: Nvidia RTX3060 Laptop

Comment: Did the 2020-era Ubuntu installer detect all of your your 2022-era hardware properly? It's common for older kernels to have problems understanding newer hardware.

Comment: Can you explain your process of installing the dual-boot in more detail? Did you follow any particular guide? Did you make any changes to windows (such as disabling fast startup)?